# Handling error in function in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I have a `sign` function, which can return an error.

```
signe :: Int -> Char
signe chiffre
    | chiffre >= 1 && chiffre <= 9 = '+'
    | chiffre == 0 = '0'
    | chiffre >= -9 && chiffre <= (-1) = '-'
    | otherwise = error "Erreur in the sign"
```

I'd like to make a simple one to return the corresponding code of the sign, *but* with error handling.

```
signes liste = [ signe x | x<-liste ]
```

I give you an example : For now, if I call

```
signes [1,3,0,-10]
```

it gives me

> ++0*** Exception: Error in sign.

I'd like to have nothing instead of Exception: `++0`.

Comment: I wanted to start my message by "hi everyone" but even with editing it's not taking in account ...

Answer (score 3):

You can, and should, use `Maybe` in such cases:

```
signe chiffre 
   | chiffre >= 1 && chiffre <= 9 = Just '+'
   ....
   | otherwise = Nothing    -- parbleu!!

signes = mapMaybe signe
```

You may need to import Data.Maybe for the `mapMaybe` function.

Comment: mapMaybes --> "Not in scope".
(I've added at the top of my sheet "import Data.List")

So i just tryed signes = map signe

But i get [Just '+' , ........, Nothing ]

Comment: It's actually just `mapMaybe`. [See the docs](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/Data-Maybe.html#v:mapMaybe).

Comment: Thank you for pointing it out, @AlexReinking , it is actually `mapMaybe` and it is in Data.Maybe. Always confuse that with `catMaybes` where there is an s at the end. COrrected above.

Comment: I had a look on the docs and i tried mapMaybe in case too, before answering.
Same problem ... Here are my functions :

    import Data.List
    
    signe chiffre
     | chiffre >= 1 && chiffre <= 9 = Just '+'
     | chiffre == 0 = Just '0'
     | chiffre >= -9 && chiffre <= (-1) = Just '-'
     | otherwise = Nothing
     
    signes = mapMaybe signe

And i'm sorry to write here but "Users with less than 10 reputation can't answer their own question for 8 hours after asking. You can answer 11/15/2013 1:56:02 AM. Until then please use comments, or edit your question instead." ...

Comment: Ingo thanks it worked !!

Thanks to all of you :) !!

Another Haskell question is :

Would it be possible to create a SIMPLE code to know if a list is increasing ?

Maybe with foldr or another thing but to make something simple ?

Comment: @Ingo No problem! I do the same thing... :)

Answer (score 2):

A better way would be to actually use the `Maybe` type which lets you literally return `Nothing` or `Just aValue`.  You could rewrite your function as

```
signe :: Int -> Maybe Char
signe chiffre
    | chiffre >= 1 && chiffre <= 9 = Just '+'
    | chiffre == 0 = Just '0'
    | chiffre >= (-9) && chiffre <= (-1) = Just '-'
    | otherwise = Nothing
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem already seems to be answered by Ingo, but I wanted to point out that since you had an error message in the original question, perhaps "Either" would be a better choice here

```
signe :: Int -> Either String Char
signe chiffre
    | chiffre >= 1 && chiffre <= 9 = Right'+'
    | chiffre == 0 = Right '0'
    | chiffre >= -9 && chiffre <= (-1) = Right '-'
    | otherwise = Left "Erreur in the sign"
```

where you can get the filtered list with

```
signes liste = [ x | Right x<-map signe liste ]
```

Both Maybe and Either are used for error checking, Either gives you the ability to pass an "Exception" up the call chain.